# My iPhone 6s is glitching like mad after the iOS 11 update, what should I do?

Tags: iphone, software-update, software, ios

Specifically, after I unlock my device many phantom buttons are being pressed and random apps are being opened by accident and things like that. Additionally, many specific clicks that I make have a massive time lag, which mixed with phantom clicks creates sheer havoc.

It's basically unusable at this point, I can't text, navigate any app properly, or even pick a phone call. I have tried restarting more than a few times to no avail.

The way I see it, these are my options:

- Somehow uninstall the new iOS, I was perfectly happy with the last one.
- Go to iCare and ask them to fix it, need to double check but I think I still have warranty. If I don't, then what?
- Keep restarting it and poking it till something happens

Please say that someone has better suggestions?

Comment: Going to apple store might be a fairly painless solution. – As a sort of a vague nudge towards... A direction.. Downgrading _might_ fix the problem... so if you google `ios 11 downgrade`, you'll likely find a few articles explaining the steps.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I’d try is downloading and installing the iOS 11.01 update.

To install the update over-the-air, go to Settings > General > Software Update.

For more information, refer to: [iOS 11.0.1: What’s New Or Changed?](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-11.0.1-release-notes-changelog-and-other-changes-for-iphone-and-ipad/)

Finally, if you get absolutely desperate you may want to consider [Downgrading iOS 11.0.1 To iOS 10.3.3 / iOS 10](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-downgrade-ios-11-beta-to-ios-10.3.2-10.3.3-tutorial/), though the window for doing this will be short!

Long term, like any iOS problem where multiple apps are misbehaving, you can always erase all content and settings after you have a good backup to make sure it’s not your settings. If the glitches continue, then restoring the device will get you a clean speedy iOS or the knowledge you need a hardware repair.

Comment: Thank you, yes I've updated to 11.01 and it seems to be more stable but is still too erratic to properly use.

Comment: I had some strange issues in IOS 11. After much fiddling I just backed it up. Erased all contents and settings and restored my backup. Problem solved. Weird.